# Pictures with a border as a map overlay

Tags: android, google-maps

I have been searching long and hard for a solution to this problem but have had no luck. I need to create the following map overlays.

[image]

The pictures will need to be placed into the borders dynamically. I have been playing around with layer lists but i am unable to get that to work. If anybody has a solution or can point me in the right direction it will be greatly appreciated.